# Selecting "runner-up" from table of teams

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Afther day's of looking for a solution i can't find a proper annswer to my problem, so :

I have a table with 4 team groups (A - D), then i have a second table linked to that grouptable with teams and the results of the games.

To select the first team in every group ( = qualified) is no problem, but to select the "runner-up" is an other thing while they have to play "Play-off" games. How do I select the "second" records in my results-lable for every group so I can populate a PlayOffGames-table with these runner-ups?

This is what I have so far :

**Step 1**:
Base tables
[image]

**Step 2**:
The ranking

[image]

**Step 3** (What I want):

[image]

With no advanced knowledge of T-sql programming I think at someting like this (Simplified !):

- **First**: Select Top 2 in Group A - ORDER BY Ranking DESC
- **Second**: From that selection: Select TOP 1 - Gives me normaly the second best from ranking in Group A
- **Third** : Save (= Add) last selection to table "TeamsPlayOff"

Repeat Step 1 true 3 for rest of the Groups...

Thanks in advance for some help in this !
(I'm using T-SQL on a MS-SQL-2016-Server)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() might do the trick, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx. if you provide sample data you may get more help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Provide more info but due to site restrictions I can't add image of tables I want.

Comment: Put the sample data here but no answers, do I something wrong ?

Comment: Still no tips ...